# E-Mail Hosting for Mid-Size-Business

Tags: email, email-server

We are a medium sized company with 5,000 employees. Every day we send and receive about 10,000 e-mails.

We want to set up our own Linux mail server (Postfix+Cyrus). What is recommended hardware for such needs?

Comment: Five thousand employees is hardly small. I have a few less users then that in my Exchange 2007 environment but do 30K messages/day, and we run between 3-4TB of space for mailboxes. We use multiple servers.

Comment: Just an FYI, 5,000 employees is not small on any scale.

Comment: You want 5000 employees using POP3 and IMAP? Have you considered looking at enterprise systems (such as Exchange)?

Comment: Yeah, sounds ignorant to focus on email when both, exchange and lotus do provide a LOT more, including scheduling in an integrated platform.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking for VPS's, take a look at Logicworks they have infiniCloud services, with CentOS , Postfix+Cyrus... all you may need for your services.